# Virtual methods in classes

Tags: oop, haxe

I am trying to make a simple extendable class and then extend it and then place the instances of the extended classes into a variable and then call the extended classes overriden methods. In other languages this is known as virtual methods. I am unable to find any information about this in Haxe.

```
class Shape
{
    public virtual function DrawShape(): Void {}
}

class Triangle extends Shape
{
    public virtual function DrawShape(): Void { printf("Triangle"); }
}

class Square extends Shape
{
    public virtual function DrawShape(): Void { printf("Square"); }
}


//usage
var myShape : Shape;

//As Triangle
myShape = new Triangle();
myShape.DrawShape(); //outputs Triangle, even though it is type Shape variable

//As Square
myShape = new Square();
myShape.DrawShape(); //outputs Square, even though it is type Shape variable
```

So, if anyonw knows how to do this in Haxe please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

virtual == override in Haxe language

Comment: Thank you, I did have that in my other code too. It turns out that a couple typos were causing the application to not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
interface IShape
{
  function drawShape () : Void;
}

class Tri implements IShape
{
  public function drawShape () : Void { return "Tri"; }
}

class Square implements IShape
{
  public function drawShape () : Void { return "Square"; }
}
```